# How to Display Cookies?

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, dns

I have setted some cookies in `example.com/place1`. When I iterate over `$_COOKIE`... it displays all cookies for my domain. Even those that are setted in `example.com/place2`. Is it possible to display cookies that are setted only in `example.com/place1/*`?

Comment: Are you certain that the `/place2` cookies were set with the correct path to `/place2` with `setcookie()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to set the path in which the cookie is available when you're sending it to the client. For example, on `example.com/place1`, set the cookie like this:

```
setcookie($name, $value, 0, '/place1/');
```

That way, the cookie will only be available inside `example.com/place1/*`.

Comment: That's what I thought... sh*t! xD Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way how to *display* (not set) cookies only for this path?

Comment: @daGrevis: You mean in javascript?

Comment: @daGrevis: Once the cookies have been set as I said above, the `$_COOKIES` array will contain *only* those cookies. There is no way to know where a cookie came from - you can only restrict where it is available (in the example above, the cookie is set so that it is only available in `example.com/place1`.